# Why does ruby output xml to console properly using put but variable contains garbage

Tags: ruby, console, format, output

I have a method that I'm sending some base64 data to.

```
def unwrap(data,key)
  d = Base64.decode64(data)
  puts unwrapped = key.decrypt(d).force_encoding("UTF-8")
  return unwrapped
end
```

The puts sends this output to the console...

```
<  D a t a >
< T o t a l > 3 < / T o t a l >
< / D a t a>
```

But the variable contains this....

```
 "<\u0000D\u0000a\u0000t\u0000a\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000C\u0000o\u0000m\u0000p\u0000u\u0
000s\u0000C\u0000o\u0000u\u0000n\u0000t\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000T\u0000o\u0000t\u0000a\u
0000<\u0000/\u0000T\u0000o\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000L\u0000i\u0000c\
u0000e\u0000d\u0000>\u00003\u0000<\u0000/\u0000L\u0000i\u0000c\u0000e\u0000n\u0000s\u0000e\u0000d\u
\u0000<\u0000B\u0000y\u0000O\u0000S\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000O\u0000S\u0000\u0000N\u0000a
```

Anyone know why?  Please note this is example data as I cannot send the actual data.  In short, the console 'put' shows me the proper data but the variable seems to contain something else?

Comment: As an aside, the use or not of forced encoding seems to make no difference nor does the encryption which is rc4.

Comment: You appear to have unicode `NUL` characters in your string.  Have you tried this w/o the `force_encoding` call?

Comment: Where does the data come from? A Windows program writing strings of `WCHAR` could explain the `NUL`s...

Comment: I've tried without the force encoding.  My real issue is that i can put the data to the console and it appears correctly but the variable contains what you see here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nick & Anders, I got on the right track and used a gsub(/\000/,'') on the result which gave me what I expected - thanks for the pair of eyes folks!

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment. You should add it as a comment to your question.

Comment: Also, patching a string with unknown encoding by applying a substitution is bad practice. While the encoding is unknown, you have no way of knowing if the substitution is a safe thing to do.